# Get Cell Value RadGrid Wpf

Tags: wpf

I Get Cell Value From DataGrid Wpf with this Code. But this don't work in RadGridView Telerik Wpf.

```
 object item = Grv_Users.SelectedItem;
 if (item == null) { return; }
 string CellID = (Grv_Users.SelectedCells[0].Column.GetCellContent(item) as TextBlock).Text;
```

Comment: This documentation may be useful: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/rows/accessing-cells-and-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It differs for selection unit you are using in your RadGridView.

- For SelectionUnit=Row

  ```
  var yourItem = gridName.SelectedItem
  ```
- For SelectionUnit=Cell

  ```
  var yourItem = gridName.SelectedCells.FirstOrDefault().Item
  ```

Code above returns object behind selected row or cell (respectively). If you want to get your cell (not an object), you can go for this:

```
   var senderElement = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
   var cell = senderElement.ParentOfType<GridViewCell>();
```

or for row:

```
   var senderElement = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
   var row = senderElement.ParentOfType<GridViewRow>();
```

If you want select cell programmatically, you should go for:

```
 var cellInfo = new GridViewCellInfo(object, columnName, gridName);

                if (!gridName.SelectedCells.Contains(cellInfo))
                {
                    gridName.SelectedCells.Add(cellInfo);
                }
```